# PWM with Oscillator does not dim LED display as expected

Tags: arduino, led, pwm, oscillator

I have a fairly successful attempt so far at driving an LED display with an Arduino Mega 2560. The Display sequences work well on their own and the Arduino seems to be doing its job sending the patterns. The part where I am struggling with is I am trying to control the intensity of the display with PWM. I am using an NE555P timer based mostly on the information here:
[555 Oscillator Tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html)

The end goal is to replace POT1 with a rotary switch to select several pre-determined brightness settings via resistors as well as a location for a photocell to provide auto dimming to adjust to ambient light. I need an external oscillator as opposed to the PWM on the Arduino board because I am planning on using an Atmega chip by itself instead of the whole Arduino when more are made.

The problem I am having is that no matter how I attempt to regulate the PWM, it has no effect on the brightness of the LEDs. They stay lit with the same intensity regardless of the timer adjustments. I have a single indicator LED attached to the timer in front of R48 that dims as expected without any problem. It is the LED array that doesn't seem affected and it outputs with the same intensity regardless of the oscillator. It would seem to me, that being that the entire voltage in should be regulated by the pulses, that they would have to dim unless they are drawing power from somewhere else. Does that seem correct? I tried replacing Transistor 17 with an FET to see if maybe it was the switching speed of the 2N2222 not being quick enough but there was no change.

Would I be better off using a different timer or do I simply have something hooked up wrong? Is there a way to isolate the voltage in to the LED array better? I am fairly stumped as to why the LEDs are unaffected by the PWM. On the schematic the connection to the Arduino Mega2560 are represented by the "Digital" labels. Any input is appreciated, I have tried switching it around but haven't had any success.!!
Update: I have made changes to the schematic based on some helpful suggestions. There are still no changes to the brightness of the display though.
Update 3:
[image: controllerC]

Having problems getting the images to insert...

Comment: "I need an external oscillator as opposed to the PWM on the Arduino board because I am planning on using an Atmega chip by itself instead of the whole Arduino when more are made." Huh? PWM is an integral part of the ATmega. I don't get your problem. Also with your 555 you are only changing its frequency, not its duty cycle.

Comment: No, changing that resistor will change both frequency and duty cycle.

Comment: LEDs in parallel = bad control of brightness on one of them usually

Comment: @jippie If I was to use an oscillation generated by the ATmega would I still use a transistor to drive the positive voltage? I did not know the mega had one on board already, which I suppose would make my life easier. I am trying to understand why the current setup isn't working if I was trying to do a similar setup without an arduino.

Comment: @Andyaka I am trying to work with an existing setup. I might be able to recreate in a better way though. The LEDs that are tied together need to remain together to work with larger displays that are wired the same.

Comment: @HiWay if you were about to butter some bread with a dirty knife I'd tell you because it's the correct and proper thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, I think, a number of issues. Try this:

Reduce C2 to .01 uF, and increase R47 to 10k. You don't list your pot value, but I'm assuming 1k. Increase this to 100k, and put a 1k in series with it. As you've got it now, the pot value gets way too low for the circuit to operate properly.

Then, you need to do a major change on your transistor output. Try something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftHdkG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that there are 2 LED outputs. Divide your LEDs into 2 equal groups and drive each group with one output. This will keep the PNP current levels within spec (3906s are only rated for 100 mA).

Alternatively, get rid of the transistor and R48/49 completely. The output current for a 555 is rated at 200 mA, that's about what your LEDs will draw. R48 and R49 are so low that you're drawing near that anyways.

Finally, I'd suggest reducing your base resistors (R17 - R32) to about 1k to 2k, just to make sure the transistors are driven hard on.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at the circuit. I made the changes to the circuit as per many of your suggestions. I did not have any 2N3906 transistors and instead used a Tip31 in place of Q1 and a TIP42 in place of Q2. They are rated at 3A and 10A respectably so I only used one instead of two. The display is still not changed by the oscillator and shines the same regardless of the changes. The inline resistor with POT1 did make it smoother, thank you for that. I will try to post the new schematic below.

Comment: Please recheck my schematic. You can still use a 2N2222 for Q1, but R54 goes to the base, not the emitter, and the emitter goes to ground.

Comment: I rechecked, I updated my schematic incorrectly. Sorry about that. With either the Tip 31 or the 2N2222 there is no change. It still is shining on brightly. Do you think the transistor be better on the negative side of the LEDs to regulate ground instead?

Comment: I tried to update the image... It keeps breaking the link...

Comment: The first thing I'd do is look carefully at the TIP data sheets. Are you sure you've got the pin order right? If you think it's EBC, you've got it wrong - it's ECB. This would explain why the LEDs are on. Second, can you turn individual LEDs on and off?

Comment: Thank you for following up with me. (with heat sink facing down) The schematic shows the pin order as BCE. It's breadboarded that way. The LED's turn off and on according to the flash pattern of the Arduino program. I have a separate LED breadboarded to test it that is not part of the LED array that is not dimming either.

Comment: Try this. Short R52. Do the LEDs turn off? Restore R52. Short R53. Do the LEDs turn off? Do you have a DMM? If you're going to do this stuff, you ought to get the cheapest one you can find. You can get one for less than $10 on eBay.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions and for your patience. I can short it out The LEDs. I have a pretty good multimeter too, the RadioShack 2200039. The PWM from the 555 seems to be fine and the mulitmeter shows the voltage switching, I am not sure where it is pulling from on the LED array side. I tried adding in an optocoupler to a 2n2222 to a TIP31 as well to see if I could further isolate it but to no avail.

Comment: Please do the following: disconnect R51 from the 555. Connect it to ground. Measure the following voltages: base of NPN, collector of NPN, base of PNP. Now connect R51 to +12. Repeat measurements. Tell me what you see.

Comment: To the base of the NPN: 11.44V / 2.177 Hz, To the collector of NPN: -.404v to -.416v / 2.1 to 2.5 Hz, To the base of the PNP: -.415v to -.413v / 2.13 to 2.16 Hz

Comment: Please do as I asked. Disconnect R51 from the 555. Connect the end that used to go to the 555 to ground. Measure. Connect the end of R51 to +12. Measure. Make all measurements with respect to ground.

Comment: Sorry about that I misunderstood. These measurements are with the meters ground connected to the circuits ground correct? I am measuring now.

Comment: OK, here's the results with meter connected to ground and R51 to ground. Base of NPN fluctuates between 116 mV and -.4mV, the collector between 12.16V and 12.2V and the Base of the PNP is also at 12.16V to 12.2V. With R51 to +12V and meter to ground: base of NPN is at 4mV spiking up to 206mV. The collector is at 12.16V to 12.2V as well at the base of the PNP. The readings are erratic at the base of the NPN.

Comment: I knocked a resistor loose, here are the numbers after reconnecting. Base of NPN fluctuates between 116 mV and -.4mV, the collector between 12.16V and 12.2V and the Base of the PNP is also at 12.16V to 12.2V. With R51 to +12V and meter to ground: base of NPN is at .89V spiking up to 1.05V. The collector is at 250mV to 350mV The base of the PNP is at 10.5V to 11.47V.

Comment: When you connect R51 to ground, do the LEDs go out?

Comment: Yes they do go out when shorted to ground.

Comment: OK. So that means that if the 555 is connected properly, when its' output is low, the LEDs should be off. Reconnect R51, and replace the 555 with a new one. Also, for what it's worth, you need to add a decoupling cap to the 555. Put a 0.1 uF ceramic between pins 1 and 8, as close to the chip as you can, and a 10 uF electrolytic as well. Look at the output of the 555 with your meter, with meter referenced to ground. Vary the pot, and the meter should give you a varying voltage reading. The LED brightness should vary at the same time.

Comment: Also, I may have been wrong about your timing capacitor. Replace it with a 0.1 uF.

Comment: The output does vary from the 555 and can PWM a single LED just fine. It just doesn't affect the LED array. I was not aware of the decoupling capacitor, I will add those in as well. I have a few other circuits with 555 timers in them that may benefit from it as well. I swapped out the 555 too just to see, I toasted a few already on this project so another won't hurt haha. I swapped the capacitor back to 0.1uf too. Same effect. I am going to hook the TIP31 to the PWM output on the Arduino to see if that works and find out what side the problem is on.

Comment: I can post the results if you'd like after hooking up the Arduino. I will most like use an ATMega chip so if that works I can port it over. I was just trying to understand why the initial concept didn't work. I really appreciate all the input man. You are awesome.

Comment: The display dims fine going through the arduino PWM... It's pulling through the 555 timer some how it seems.

Comment: Are you sure that the 555 ground is the same as the LED ground? Is it possible they aren't connected?

Comment: Yes they are the same ground. The PWM from the 555 work fine on a single LED just not on the whole array. The PWM from the Arduino dims it just fine. The combination of the NPN and PNP transistors works really well and allows it to get full intensity down to off. With a single TIP31 I can only get up to around 50% bright max.

Comment: Then that's what it takes to get the full range. And that's why my answer told you to change your output driver from an NPN to a PNP (with an NPN to provide adequate base drive).

Comment: The NPN base drive was the ticket. Thank you for all of your input, it was really helpful.